# UPDATE SUM +1 em valor decimal

Tags: postgresql

Preciso montar um `UPDATE` em uma tabela porém, no campo valor: '1481126826.2363343', preciso que esse número vire '1481126826.2363344'

A `query` que estou tentando e a seguinte :

```
UPDATE callcenter.chamada_agente  
   SET uniqueid = SUM('1481126826.2363343'  + 1)
 WHERE id_chamada_agente  = 32408 
   AND tipo_chamada = 'MANUAL'
   AND datahora_inicio BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-15 23:59:59';
```

Podem me ajudar ?

Comment: E qual é o problema? erro? ou o número vira um diferente do esperado?

Comment: Error de sintaxe. Sou iniciante com o postgresql

Comment: Coloca na pergunta a mensagem de erro. Veja se `SET uniqueid = uniqueid + 1` funciona

Comment: Tentei fazer isso porem ele vai somar '1481126826   <--  2363343 '

Comment: Tem que somar na casa decimal

Comment: E com `.1` no lugar do `1` ?

Comment: Nao Funciona tentei aqui ..

Comment: Deu erro ou somou errado?

Comment: Erro de sintaxe

Comment: Então coloca `0.1` no lugar de `.1`

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o `nextval()`:

```
UPDATE callcenter.chamada_agente  
   SET uniqueid = nextval(uniqueid) --> Assim
 WHERE id_chamada_agente  = 32408 
   AND tipo_chamada = 'MANUAL'
   AND datahora_inicio BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-15 23:59:59';
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta somar com ele mesmo:

```
SET uniqueid = uniqueid  + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`SUM()` é uma função de agregação, não vai servir para o que você quer. Para isso, basta somar com o valor que quer incrementar.

```
UPDATE callcenter.chamada_agente  
   SET uniqueid = uniqueid + 0.0000001 -- uniqueid é o que já tem o valor '1481126826.2363343', certo?
 WHERE id_chamada_agente  = 32408 
   AND tipo_chamada = 'MANUAL'
   AND datahora_inicio BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-15 23:59:59';
```